# PSQL - please help update table 1 contents from table 2

Tags: postgresql

this is my table schema and the code i am using to try to copy the customer ID from table 2 to table

```
my-server=# \d t1
Table "public.t1"
Column,Type,Collation,Nullable,Default
id,bigint,,,
pp_id,bigint,,,
customer_id,integer,,,
my-server=# 

my-server=# \d t2
Table "public.t2"
Column,Type,Collation,Nullable,Default
id,bigint,,,
customer_id,integer,,,
my-server=#
```

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
FROM
        t2
WHERE
        t1.pp_id=t2.id;

my-server=# \i /home/john/test.psql;
psql:/home/sally/test.psql:7: ERROR:  column "t1" of relation "t1" does not exist
LINE 2: SET t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
            ^
```

Comment: `SET t1.customer_id = ` must be  `SET customer_id = `